# Winmerge doesn't work as expected

Tags: svn, winmerge

When I write a source code with linux and windows and compare it with winmerge, winmerge shows that the files have changed, although nothing has changed. See picture in the attachment below right (win and unix) ? Is there some way to fix it ?
[image]

Comment: What is incorrect is not obvious by the scr

Answer (score 3):

Linux and Windows systems have different end of line symbols.

Most likely the files are different because each line is now terminated differently, but Winmerge is then set to ignore differences in end of line characters and thus the bulk of the lines are identical then.

Answer (score 0):

I have WinMerge here:  V12.16.14.0 64-bit.

I have most of the compare options set to default.

A large compare shows all files identical (two different computers and the files are indeed the same).

[image: WinMerge]

Perhaps try the following:  Uninstall WinMerge, download the most recent 64-bit and install that. Make sure (at least initially) that folder compare options are default. I have been using the 64-bit version for a year or more and it works great.